# Dotmailer connector API error while disabled from admin panel

Tags: magento2

My Magento 2 module is **disabled** from my admin panel..

[image]

but i still got this **exception** in exception.log file
[image]

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email

Comment: What you did to solve this issue

Comment: i run that commands ....! after that dotmailer extension disappear from my admin panel

Comment: great !! was my comment helpful ?

Comment: Yes It was helpful

Comment: Sould i post it as answer if it was helpful so it can help future readers

Comment: Yeah sure why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79367/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-ammad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize bin/Magento via SSH.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email 

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you have another, different language as back-end user as en_US, add the specific flag to the deploy-paramter. 
I.e.:

```
setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE fr_FR `.
```

If this still doesn't work, try deleting the content of pub/static/. You can do this with:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
```